# What does “lack of organization” mean?

Tags: tense

Here is the context:

> Letter by Ryouji Uehara  1922: Born in Nagano Prefecture. 1943:
>   Entered Keio University. December 1943: Drafted into the Imperial Army
>   of Japan. May 1945: Died while diving into a US carrier near Okinawa
>   as a Kamikaze pilot. 22 years old at time of death.
>
> "My thoughts
>
> I am eternally honored to be selected as a member of the Special
>   Attack Squadron¹ of my great motherland Japan.
>
> To come to think of it, based on the power of logic of the theories I
>   learned through my life as a student–and maybe I am going to be
>   accused of holding liberal thoughts because of this–it is clear that
>   liberty is going to triumph in the end. Freedom, a part of human
>   nature, can never be destroyed. Even if it looks as if it is being
>   repressed, deep down inside, it will always fight back and in the end
>   will always win. I believe this is fundamentally true as Croce of
>   Italy² put it... It is an indisputable fact that authoritarian or totalitarian states, even if temporarily successful, will in the end most certainly be defeated. We
>   can witness this fact in the fate of the Axis Countries (Japan,
>   Germany and Italy) during the current world war. Fascism in Italy and
>   Nazism in Germany have already been defeated. Authoritarian states are
>   falling now one after another as if they were buildings with no
>   foundation. Reality is proving the truth that has repeatedly been
>   proven throughout history. The great nature of freedom will continue
>   to be proven forever and ever in such ways. I am so happy to know that
>   what I believed in was true, despite the horrific nature of these
>   events for my motherland. I believe that ideas are what drive all the
>   struggles of our days. By understanding these ideas, we can clearly
>   predict their outcomes.
>
> My dream of making my motherland, my beloved Japan, into a great
>   empire like the British Empire of the past has perished. If Japan had
>   been led by those who truly loved the country, Japan would not have
>   been in the state that it is today. To be a Japanese proudly walking
>   tall anywhere in the world–this was my dream.
>
> A friend of mine once said that a Kamikaze pilot is merely a part in a
>   machine. A device that controls the plane, nothing human, no feelings,
>   no sanity either. He is merely a molecule in a bunch of machines lured
>   into an enemy carrier like a magnet. If we were sane, well this is the
>   unthinkable, or as they³ put it, it is “suicide.” This is
>   something that can only be thought up in Japan–a country of
>   spiritualism. As a mere machine I have no rights to say, but I only
>   hope and ask the people of Japan that they make this motherland I love
>   into a great nation in the future.
>
> If I die in this sorry state of mind, maybe my death will be deemed
>   worthless. Therefore, as I said in the beginning, I am eternally
>   honored to be selected as a member of the Special Attack Squadron.
>
> Once on a plane, I am just a part in a machine. But when I’m not
>   there, I have feelings and emotions too. When my beloved girlfriend
>   died, my feelings died with her. When I think that death is only a
>   path to heaven where she will be waiting for me, I have no fear of it.
>   Tomorrow, I will be taking off on my mission. I know my thoughts are
>   extreme and should not be publicly stated. But these are my truly
>   honest feelings. Please forgive me for writing whatever came to my
>   mind with a total **lack of organization.** Tomorrow, one believer of
>   freedom will perish from the face of this earth. He will have a sad
>   look, but deep inside he will be content.
>
> I have said everything that I wanted to say. Please forgive me for
>   being so frank.
>
> <sub>¹ The so-called "Kamikaze"</sub>
>   <sub>² Italian Philosopher, 1866-1955</sub>
>   <sub>³ The enemy</sub>

Does it mean that he had humbled himself because he had a different opinion about war from that of his country/Air force (organization)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Please forgive me for writing whatever came to my mind with a total lack of organization.

This simply means that the author feels he has been writing *whatever came to his mind* without *organizing* the things that he wanted to write.

It says nothing about the organization he works for, the organization of his country's war effort, or anything else. It simply means:

> I am sorry for writing all this in an non-organized way.

Comment: Is "lack of oraganization" an Idiom ? Or you just saw it from the context ?

Comment: lack of something means _absence_ of something. So, yes, the context seems pretty clear: _I wrote [this] with a lack of organization_

Answer (score 0):

It means the ideas are disorganized. Lack of = missing something.